# ggplot2 "Ignoring unknown parameters" error message

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is the code,  the legend for Gender is not showing up on my plot.

```
ggplot(Experience, aes(fill=factor(Gender),x=Exper, y=Sal95, size= Rank))+
+     geom_point(stroke= 0.5, color=6, shape=21, alpha=0.4)+
+     geom_smooth(SE=FALSE, method = "lm")+
+     labs(title= "Experience, Rank, and Salary", subtitle ="Men Vs Women", 
+          y="1995 Salary", x="Experience", caption = 
+            "Source-https://www.kaggle.com/hjmjerry/gender-discrimination")+
+     scale_size(range = c(3,6),name = "Rank")+
+     scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE, guide=FALSE, option="E")+
+     ylab("1995 Salary")+
+     xlab("Experience")+
+     scale_y_log10()
```

Here is the error I’m getting below

> geom_smooth() using formula 'y ~ x'
> Warning message:
> Ignoring unknown parameters: SE

I cannot seem to see why it is not showing up and running this on macOS High Sierra. Is anyone getting this error too?

Comment: The error is in `geom_smooth(SE=FALSE, method = "lm")`. Use `se=FALSE`  instead...

Comment: Try without option `guide=FALSE` in scale_fill_viridis.

Comment: Thanks, guys for the help. The first option did not work but  @Stephan, guide=FALSE in scale_fill_viridis -worked!